# Create a curve at selected vertex in the direction of the normal maya

Tags: python, maya

I want to create a script that will create a curve at each vertex of a polygon in the direction of the normal. I have a script that will duplicate a curve and move it to a curve but the problem is that when its a curved surface the curves are created withen the mesh. I have tried using Google Uncle but i could not find anything that was helpful. If anyone knows how to do it or a forum that is related to this topic please assist me....

```
import pymel.core as pm
obj = pm.PyNode('pSphereShape1')
for i in obj.vtx:
    new_curve = cmds.duplicate(cmds.ls('curveShape1')[0])
    #new_curve = cmds.listRelatives(new_curve[0],c = 1)
    print "%s :: %s"%(i,i.getPosition(space = 'world'))
    cmds.setAttr('%s.translateX'%(new_curve[0]),i.getPosition(space = 'world')[0])
    cmds.setAttr('%s.translateY'%(new_curve[0]),i.getPosition(space = 'world')[1])
    cmds.setAttr('%s.translateZ'%(new_curve[0]),i.getPosition(space = 'world')[2])
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask])

Comment: Please post your script so we know what you've tried and can help determine what the issue is.